# How to make tree view in ss-multiselect-dropdown?

Tags: angular, dropdown

How to create tree view in dropdown ss-multiselect-dropdown?
Something like in the picture? I use angular 8.

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell which angular version are you using to implement this drop-down ?

Comment: I use angular 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made something simple. If the element is main I will add two minus
-- United States -- and the Id was multiplay by -1. This solved problem with the same id in the main element (country)

Answer (score 0):

@mbielecki1

We have checked your problem and there is a very good and efficient package available for it.

Please refer : https://github.com/leovo2708/ngx-treeview

It is very helpful and quite good demos are also available for the same.

Comment: I would rather prefer those ss-multiselect-dropdown :) but thanks for help

Comment: Yes we suggest this package as it has good contributors and good support as well.